# Facebook integation in an ios app

Tags: iphone, facebook

How to integrate facebook in an iOS application ?

I have tried it once but I didn't understand **how to generate a key from a developer account**.

If it is possible then please provide me with a document which describes everything in detail

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want .... How to generate a app key on fb developer account or how to implement FBGraph in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate facebook using the FBGraph method. Here you have to first import the JSON and the FBGraph frameworks. After that write the following code :-

```
NSString *client_id = @"130902823636657";
self.fbGraph =[[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

[fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];




- (void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender
{
if ((fbGraph.accessToken==nil)||([fbGraph.accessToken length]==0)) {

    [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];            }    
else
{
    NSMutableDictionary *Variables=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    FbGraphFile *graph_File=[[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:imageCollage.image];
    [Variables setObject:graph_File forKey:@"file"];
    [Variables setObject:@"" forKey:@"message"];
```